# sed on cygwin can only replace one character?

Tags: sed, windows, character-encoding, cygwin, xml

I'm trying to replace an XML element in 20+ files on Windows using sed and cygwin. The line is:

```
cd "D:\Backups\Tasks"
sed -i 's~<StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>~<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>~g' "Task_01.xml"
```

This replaces nothing. However, if I try:

```
sed 's~<~[~g' "Task_01.xml"
```

It outputs:

```
[AllowHardTerminate>true[/AllowHardTerminate>
[StartWhenAvailable>true[/StartWhenAvailable>
[RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false[/RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
```

However, if I try to add just a single character, it just outputs the document as-is:

```
sed 's~<B~[B~g' "Task_01.xml"
```

The above does nothing. What am I doing wrong? Is the chevron a special character or am I misusing sed? Or is it a fault in cygwin?

Comment: Can't reproduce, even when running from powershell.exe. May the file contain some hidden character? Try `sed -n l < MyFile.xml` to reveal them.

Comment: I can not reproduce this in Cygwin.

Comment: I'd bet it's a UTF-16 file. Try `iconv -f utf-16 < file.xml | sed...`

Comment: Have you thought of using a different string delimiter character?  Like maybe semi-colon (;)?

Comment: I use `~` since it's just about the only character that I can guarantee isn't in these XML files. Since they're Windows tasks, they store commands which can be `;` delimited, so I wouldn't be able to do a find/replace on those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probably, that file is encoded in UTF-16, that is with 2 or 4 bytes per characters, probably even with a Byte-Order-Mark at the beginning.

The characters that are shown in your sample (all ASCII characters) are typically encoded on 2 bytes, the first or second of which (depending on whether it's a big-enfian or little-endian UTF-16 encoding) being 0 and the other one being the ASCII/Unicode code. The 0 byte is typically invisible on a terminal, so that text appears OK when dumped there as the rest is just ASCII, but in effect the text contains:

```
<[NUL]S[NUL]t[NUL]a[NUL]r[NUL]t[NUL]W[NUL]h[NUL]e[NUL]n[NUL]...
```

You'd need to convert that text to your locale's charset for `sed` to be able to deal with it. Note that UTF-16 cannot be used as a character encoding in a locale on Unix. You won't find a locale that uses UTF-16  as its character encoding.

```
iconv -f utf-16 < Task_01.xml |
  sed 's~<StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>~<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>~g' |
  iconv -t utf-16 > Task_01.xml.out
```

That assumes the input has a BOM. If not, you need to determine if it's big endian or little endian (probably little endian) and change that `utf-16` to `utf-16le` or `utf-16be`.

If the locale's charset is UTF-8, there shouldn't be anything lost in translation even if the text contains non-ASCII characters.

As Cygwin's `sed` is typically GNU `sed`, it will also be able to deal with that type of binary (since it contains NUL bytes) input by itself, so you can also do something like:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i 's/t\x00r\x00u\x00e/f\x00a\x00l\x00s\x00e/g' Task_01.xml
```

The `file` command should be able to tell you if the input is indeed UTF-16. You can use `sed -n l` or `od -tc` to see those hidden NUL characters. Example of little-endian UTF-16 text with BOM:

```
$ echo true | iconv -t utf-16 | od -tc
0000000 377 376   t  \0   r  \0   u  \0   e  \0  \n  \0
0000014
$ echo true | iconv -t utf-16 | sed -n l
\377\376t\000r\000u\000e\000$
\000$
$ echo true | iconv -t utf-16 | file -
/dev/stdin: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with no line terminators
```

To process several files with `zsh`/`bash`/`ksh93`:

```
set -o pipefail
for file in ./*.xml; do
  cp -ai "$file" "$file.bak" &&
    iconv -f utf-16 < "$file.bak" |
      sed 's~<StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>~<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>~g' |
      iconv -t utf-16 > "$file" &&
    rm -f "$file.bak"
done
```

Comment: Yes yes yes! I noticed that when I did `sed 's/\</[/g' file.xml` that it changed every tag to `[P[a[r[e[n[t>` or something like it. It must have been picking up the null characters and replacing them. The XML file does indeed have a BOM and it is a Windows-generated file. I'll try these changes when I get home.

Comment: Of course, the whole point of using sed was so that I could replace the tag in all of the files in a single folder, and this means I'd have to do one file at a time so I might as well use Notepad2 at that point. I don't know if a UTF-16 compatible find and replace program exists for Windows.

Comment: I ran the for loop and got `cp: failed to preserve ownership for './Task_01.xml.bak': Permission denied` for every single file I tried to run it on (changed extension to .bak instead of .back because I have a registry key for .bak to open in Notepad2). It also doesn't seem to have changed the tag within the file.

Comment: I removed the `-a` flag from the `cp` command and it worked! Thanks a lot. I'll be sure to use this with all of the mass updates that I have to make to XML files.

Answer (score 2):

Place your `sed` command inside a file, like say, sed.cmds & then invoke `sed` as:

```
sed -i -f "sed.cmds" "MyFile.xml"
```

Also try to change the delimiter to `_`, like as:

`s_<BooleanTag>true</BooleanTag>_<BooleanTag>false</BooleanTag>_g`